# Sub paths in url returning an internal server error with nginx and express server using react router

Tags: express, nginx

So basically I have an express server running on port 4000 that Nginx is redirecting to with a proxy_pass. When I access the root of my domain in the browser (https://www.buildingblockscms.tech/) everything works fine. But when I refresh any sub-routes I've navigated to or try to access them directly (https://www.buildingblockscms.tech/dashboard) I get an internal server error.

The react app running on my express server works absolutely fine with react-router-dom when ran locally but something is up with my Nginx config.

I've been trying to solve this all day, any help is GREATLY appreciated.

This is my sites-available/default file in Nginx.

```
server {
        root /var/www/index.html;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name buildingblockscms.tech www.buildingblockscms.tech;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/; #whatever port your app runs$
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_redirect     off;
    }
```

And this is my server file running on port 4000:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const graphqlHTTP = require('express-graphql');
const auth = require('./middleware/auth');

const app = express();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(express.json());

// enable files upload
// app.use(
//   fileUpload({
//     createParentPath: true
//   })
// );

// DB Config
const db = process.env.mongoURI || require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// Connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(db, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected...'))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

// Use Routes
app.use('/api/content-types', require('./routes/api/content-types'));
app.use('/api/sites', require('./routes/api/sites'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
app.use('/api/pages', require('./routes/api/pages'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/api/auth'));

// GraphQL Route
app.use(
  '/graphiql',
  auth,
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: require('./routes/client-graphql/schema'),
    graphiql: true,
  })
);

// Serve static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: hey man were you able to fix configuration with react-router.

Comment: I am having the same issue react-router is not working on server where as locally it works fine.